# Python: How do I slice a list based on variable type

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, slice

I am trying to slice a list into a list of lists, whereby the original list is sliced at the point where a string type object is detected e.g.

```
array = ['Hello',1,2,3,'Goodbye',4,6,'Bye',7,8,9,5]
```

to

```
new_array = [['Hello',1,2,3],['Goodbye',4,6],['Bye',7,8,9,5]]
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator function for this, e.g.:

```
def gen(arr):
    r = []
    for el in arr:
        if r and isinstance(el, str):
            yield r
            r = []
        r.append(el)
    if r:
        yield r

>>> list(gen(array))
[['Hello', 1, 2, 3], ['Goodbye', 4, 6], ['Bye', 7, 8, 9, 5]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much! That's really interesting. I've never come across generator functions before. Do you have a good website that you'd recommend that discusses them?

Comment: The official docs should get you a long part of the way: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators